# Is there a way to play 5.1 surround via Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

I have several albums on DVD with both Dolby Digital 5.1 and DTS 5.1 versions. I'd like to be able to listen to them without dealing with physical disks all the time.

I have no problem using `ffmpeg` to pull the audio data out and stick it in a file, but I haven't been able to find the magic format that will let it play via Apple TV. [I've read](http://www.roughlydrafted.com/RD/RDM.Tech.Q1.07/147048D8-D8B7-45E7-9A97-3CD5B4C2B75A.html) that the Apple TV doesn't need to understand the format, it just needs to send the data to a receiver that does, which makes perfect sense, but how do I get it to do that? I can't get a WAV containing DTS to work.

If the solution ends up being to stick the AC3 data in a video container, that's fine, but ideally, I just want to store/play the audio (and ideally, it would be the DTS version).

I have both a 1st and a 3rd generation Apple TV (a.k.a. the Apple TV 2 with 1080p support), so any solution, old or new, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The Apple TV can pass through 5.1 AC-3 to a receiver if you set up the file correctly. Apple has the full details in a [knowledge base article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1755), but basically you need to set up your `mp4`/`m4v` file with a stereo AAC as the default audio track, then put your AC-3 track after it, disabled. On the Apple TV, you need to enable it by turning on **Dolby Digital Out** in the Audio Settings.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I’ll keep looking for an audio-only solution, though. :-) FYI, the Dolby Digital setting can be left on “Auto”.

Comment: Actually what may work better for you is encoding your albums to Apple Lossless (ALAC). It can technically handle 5.1 sound, and the Apple TV supports it (although the specs don't explicitly mention multichannel, just support for Apple Lossless). [XLD](http://tmkk.pv.land.to/xld/index_e.html) should be able to encode to 5.1 ALAC, but you may need to use something else to convert from AC3 to a format XLD can read (probably wav).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that once you have a suitable WAV file containing the DTS data, you can convert it to ALAC (though DTS is already compressed and there's not much of a space savings). The trick is creating the WAV file. I've been working on a Python script to do it, but no luck so far.

Comment: One further update to the answer… If you create a video container, it no longer seems to be necessary to include stereo AAC at all. You can have just one AC3 audio track.

Comment: ffmpeg should be able to do multichannel AC3 to wav without issues, have you tried that?

Comment: I’ve tried various things in `ffmpeg`. It will convert other formats to WAV just fine (2 channel or 5 channel), but that’s not what I need.

iTunes won’t import a WAV unless it’s 2 channel. There’s a particular type of file (and there are many examples on-line) that *looks* like a 2-channel WAV (to iTunes and `ffmpeg`), but it contains 5.1 data. When played it simply streams the original DTS to your receiver.

So it’s not really a WAV file, but a container that looks like one.

Comment: There's a related question [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61203/are-there-known-dts-or-dolby-digital-encoded-videos-readily-available-on-apple-t?lq=1) about the availability of DTS and ac3 encoded videos for testing on Apple TV.

Comment: @robmathers: No need to disable the AC-3 track, and you don't technically even need the AAC stereo track.  However, I highly recommend adding the AAC stereo track first, as this will make it compatible with the built-in Videos app on iOS devices (they won't play on iOS without the AAC stereo track, unless you're using a non-Apple AC-3-capable player, and there are few of those left anymore).

Answer (score 0):

AppleTV will pass through an AC3 5.1 audio track if it's a secondary audio track (with AAC the primary). You need to embed the audio into an m4v file and make sure all tracks have the same language setting (including "Unknown"), but you can use empty video and AAC tracks and just add the AC3 Passthru track as the only actual data. Then if you mark it as "Music Video" in iTunes, iTunes will treat it as if it's a music file (and it'll show up with other music files). Things get more complex with music that segues between tracks, since iTunes cannot stream "videos" seamlessly one into another like it can with music.